# Angular 2 and DevExpress - DevExtreme

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, systemjs-builder

We are writing an angular 2 application utilising virtually all of the various components throughout the system somewhere. In development the page load times are incredibly slow as devexpress load each of the modules from a separate js file and don't provide an minified version for development.

Is there any way after running npm install I can get the devexpress package minified. Within the angular app we use systemjs so it would need to be compatible with that.

I'm new to this kind of thing so any examples would be very helpful please.

Comment: I haven't experienced serious load times, but I am using webpack.  Would be curious to know what other people's experiences are.

Comment: We are using webpack too and we are very satisfied with speed... in Chrome. In IE11 loading is a lot slower.

Comment: In production where the scripts are minified then performance is fine, however when developing it uses node_modules and therefore loads the whole app loads ~1500 files over the network. I am looking to reduce this if possible

Comment: You are right, in development environment devexpress is slow, but if you setup your webpack config file, then you can minify your vendor's javascript files and include them.